# RestSharp - Authorization Header not coming across to WCF REST service

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp, restful-authentication

I am trying to call a locally hosted WCF REST service over HTTPS with basic auth.

This works and the Authorization header comes thru just fine and all is happy:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertficate;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost/MyService/MyService.svc/");
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add(
  System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization,
  "Basic " + this.EncodeBasicAuthenticationCredentials("UserA", "123"));

WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (webStream != null)
    {
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
        {
            string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use RestSharp however, the Authorization header never comes thru on the request:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertficate;

var credentials = this.EncodeBasicAuthenticationCredentials("UserA", "123");

var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://localhost/MyService/MyService.svc/");   
var restRq = new RestSharp.RestRequest("/");
restRq.Method = Method.GET;
restRq.RootElement = "/";
restRq.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
var restRs = client.Execute(restRq);
```

What am i doing wrong with the RestSharp method?

I know that the AddHeader method works because this:

```
restRq.AddHeader("Rum", "And Coke");
```

will come thru, only "Authorization" seems stripped out/missing.

Comment: having the same here, any luck solving that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

instead of adding the header 'manually' do the following:

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://localhost/MyService/MyService.svc/");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("UserA", "123");
```

Comment: ok. you need to use fiddler to see what exactly is received server-side

Comment: i'm not sure you need that forward slash in your `RestRequest`- have you tried without that, ie just empty string?

Comment: Now i'm trying to figure out how to use Fiddler2 to catch localhost traffic... :(

Comment: http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Observe-Traffic/Troubleshooting/NoTrafficToLocalhost

Comment: I had the same issue and I found out the problem was a trailing slash (/) in the baseUrl of the RestClient constructor. This one fails: "https://localhost/MyService/MyService.svc". This one succeeds: "https://localhost/MyService/MyService.svc/".

Comment: Had a similar same issue, @ValerioGentile. After defining the client, I created the request: var request = new RestRequest("api/2.0/whatever", Method.GET); -- you need a trailing '/' after whatever if you have any parameters defined.

Answer (score 14):

I used milano's answer to get my REST service call to work (using GET)

```
    Dim client2 As RestClient = New RestClient("https://api.clever.com")

    Dim request2 As RestRequest = New RestRequest("me", Method.GET)

    request2.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " & j.access_token, ParameterType.HttpHeader)

    Dim response2 As IRestResponse = client2.Execute(request2)
    Response.Write("** " & response2.StatusCode & "|" & response2.Content & " **")
```

The key was making sure there was a space after the word 'Bearer' but this may apply to any type of custom token authorization header

Comment: @cs0815 This was the answer that helped me too, however whatever the accepted answer is apparently helped the OP, so I guess that's the point of it.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use **ParameterType.HttpHeader** parameter:

```
request.AddParameter("Authorization", "data", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
```

Comment: I would do that but as an implementation of `IAuthenticator` and then adding it to the `RestClient` instance.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the response from my rest API using this piece of code:
My API was returning server error and I used:

```
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
```

```
var request = new RestRequest("/antiforgerytokensso", Method.Get);

restClient.Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(accessToken);

var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(request);

Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
```