# Using RestSharp, how do I execute a POST request to my ASP.NET Web API with an oAuth2 Bearer token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

After I have obtained an access token from my API, I am calling this method:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage BatchGeocode([FromBody] InputDataClass inputData)
{
    //do stuff, return a HttpResponseMessage
}
```

I can make the request and get the expected response using Postman like this:

[image: HTTP request using Postman]

I am attempting to call the same API method in an application with RestSharp, using the same url and input data as above:

```
var client = new RestClient(url);

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);      
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiInput), ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Where `apiInput` is my object that matches the API input parameter - when serialized with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` I get a string identical to what is being used in the body of my API request via Postman.

When this runs the message I get back is "Authorization has been denied for this request." My break point in the API that I have running locally is not being hit, which leads me to belie that I am not structuring my request properly in the calling application.  Using RestSharp, how do I execute a POST request to my ASP.NET Web API with an oAuth2 Bearer token?

Comment: Hmmmm - have you tried a tool like `Fiddler 4` to capture the request and verify that RestSharp is actually adding the token appropriately?  It might be as simple as the string in the token is wrong

Comment: Yes, it looks like the request from RestSharp is not quite the same.  [Here is the diff](http://www.diff-online.com/view/593b2b65482b0) between the two requests as compared in Fiddler.  It looks like the "Authorization" header is not in the RestSharp request - this is what I am not quite sure how to do.  I wasn't able to find any applicable examples or documentation on how to use a Bearer token with an Authorization header in a RestSharp request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a cursory search it appears that you may need to call the overload with the `ParameterType` value.

```
request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
```

That being said it also appears that RestSharp would like you to use a different method to perform authentication ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17763033/594354)), but that is beyond the scope of my knowledge with RestSharp.

Comment: Thanks for that link to the previous question - it is exactly what I needed.  I added the Authorization token as a parameter to the request, and I am now able to execute the request and receive the expected response.