# Authorization header is incorrect error, while converting php to restsharp api post call

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a php api call in C# RestSharp. I already did exactly same as it is done in php however I am still getting error response: "Authorization header is incorrect". I am not good at php so anyone can advice if I am doing exactly same in RestSharp as it is done in php?

PHP example code:

```
<?
$clientId = "your_client_id";
$secret = "your_secret";

$url = "https://www.badboy.com/api/1.1/request/create";
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($clientId . ":" . $secret)
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

$data =
    [
        "reference"=>"some-reference-value",
        "environment"=>"sandbox",
        "name"=>"John Smith",
        "email"=>"myemail@email.com",
        "scope"=>"documents(passport)",
        "address" => [
            "address1"=>"Unit 8-10",
            "town"=>"London",
            "postcode"=>"SW6 2UZ",
            "country"=>"GBR"
        ]
    ];

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
?>
```

C# RestSharp Code:

```
string endpoint = @"https://www.badboy.com/";
            string clientId = @"your_client_id";
            string secretCode = @"your_secret";

            var client = new RestClient(endpoint);
            var request = new RestRequest("api/1.8/request/create", Method.Post);

            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            string combine = clientId + ":" + secretCode;
            var bt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(combine);
            string encodedSecretCode = Convert.ToBase64String(bt);

            //request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            //request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedSecretCode);

            Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedSecretCode);
            request.AddHeaders(headers);

            var data = new DataBody();
            data.reference = "some-dd-value";
            data.environment = "ss";
            data.name = "John Smith";
            data.email = "me@email.com";
            data.scope = "documents(foo)";
            data.address.address1 = "Unit 8-10";
            data.address.town = "London";
            data.address.postcode = "SW6 2UZ";
            data.address.country = "GBR";
                



            string jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            request.AddBody(jsonData);  

            var response = client.Execute(request)
```

C# Model:

```
public class Address
    {
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        public string address2 { get; set; }
        public string address3 { get; set; }
        public string town { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataBody
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string client_key { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public string callback_uri { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string redirect_uri { get; set; }
        public string mandatory { get; set; }
        public string user { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string send_choice { get; set; }
        public string tabs_order { get; set; }
        public string environment { get; set; }
        public bool use_defaults { get; set; }
        public Address address { get; set; } = new Address();
    }
```

Where I can improve in C# RestSharp code any idea?

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17763033

Comment: There have been changes to libraries.  See latest documentation : https://restsharp.dev/authenticators.html#oauth2

Comment: @Matthew I tried that already same error.